# access 2016 append multifield to one field

Tags: ms-access, append, ms-access-2016, ms-query, jquery-append

[![enter image description here][1]][1]good day to you all.

I have a table with some field like attached file T_Jadwal2.jpg. https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPuBg.jpg
I need the the table insert to other table with the difference way format like T_Jadwal3.jpg https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRg7y.jpg
Kindly to have the solution in query to append the T_Jadwal2 to T_Jadwal3

Thank you.

Regards,
Fernando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a *union query* like this:

```sql
Select ID_Jadwal, [Shift], Supervisor As Nm_Karyawan, "Supervisor" As Posisi
From YourTable
Where Supervisor Is Not Null
Union All
Select ID_Jadwal, [Shift], Printing, "Printing"
From YourTable
Where Printing Is Not Null
Union All
Select ID_Jadwal, [Shift], Tinta, "Tinta"
From YourTable
Where Tinta Is Not Null
Union All
Select ID_Jadwal, [Shift], Cylinder, "Cylinder"
From YourTable
Where Cylinder Is Not Null
Union All
Select ID_Jadwal, [Shift], Dry, "Dry"
From YourTable
Where Dry Is Not Null
Union All
Select ID_Jadwal, [Shift], Extrusion, "Extrusion"
From YourTable
Where Extrusion Is Not Null
Union All
Select ID_Jadwal, [Shift], Slitting, "Slitting"
From YourTable
Where Slitting Is Not Null
Union All
Select ID_Jadwal, [Shift], Rewind, "Rewind"
From YourTable
Where Rewind Is Not Null
```

Use this as source in your append query.

Comment: Sorry @Gustav, I miss one field. I Have edit the question on the picture.
Kindly to have your assist please......

Comment: You should be able to "see the picture" - how to add or remove a field (section) to/from the union query.

Comment: the miss field is the filed.name to input beside the current record.